# Uninstalled app coming up in update list in play store

Tags: google-play-store, swiftkey

I uninstalled an app using a long tap shortcut that comes on One plus two mainscreen, which I guess is also the time when there is an update waiting for this app because the next time I opened the Play Store, an update shows up for the app. When trying to update and then uninstall (this time from Play Store), it still keeps showing up in *Updates* list and the whole things repeat.

The app is *Swiftkey Keyboard*, if that helps. Any recommendations on permanently removing the app would be helpful. Android v6.0.1, OS: OxygenOS v3.0.2

- I tried *Settings > Apps* and there is no uninstall option, instead there is a disable option next to force stop. In play store, there is update option which doesn't help as I stated earlier.
- I doubt if it is a system app, because I voluntarily installed it (from Google Play Store as I remember; I enabled installation from unknown sources only after the release of Pokemon go, I am not aware of any other possible ways of side-loading)
- The app doesn't show up in *Device Administrators* (there's only Android Device Manager and another paid app visible in device administrators)
- I disabled it, it stopped showing up in updates, keyboard menu and elsewhere, but it still is taking up that internal storage as shown in *Settings > Apps.*

Comment: Next possible cause is, it seems Swiftkey Keyboard is a system app. In this case, you can only uninstall *all applied updates* (read: reset to factory setting). If you want to uninstall the app itself, you'd need root access and use uninstaller app that has root access.

Comment: That leaves a few questions: 1) installed from what source? Especially if side-loaded, it could have come with something malicious "attached to it". 2) Have you checked whether it registered as device admin? That might prevent uninstallation. But [according to Swiftkey support](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201457602-How-do-I-uninstall-SwiftKey-Keyboard-for-Android-), that should not be the case.

Comment: @Izzy from google play store as I remember. I enabled installation from unknown sources only after the release of Pokemon go, I am not aware of any other possible ways of side-loading. 2) No, only _Android Device Manager_ and another paid app are visible in device administrators.

Comment: OK, I'm out of ideas then. Are you running Linux (or at least Cygwin) on your computer, and can access your device via ADB? Then we could at least easily figure where the `.apk` file (and other resources of the app) are located, to make sure of "system app or not". My little tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) generates a nice report on that (amongst other things).

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I run Linux on my computer, I will verify and comeback thanks.